# android how to insert array data into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i followed  [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays) google  firebase guide to  insert array of data
 in database.
 what i have done is to create below code and it works fine:

```
 memberDatabaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("member");

 save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Map<String, String> member = new HashMap<>();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

       for(int i=1; i<5;i++){
                String value= "member "+String.valueOf(i);
                String id= memberDatabaseReference.push().getKey();
                  member.put("id", id);
                  member.put("name", value);
                sampleArray sampleArray = new sampleArray(member);
                memberDatabaseReference.child(id).setValue(sampleArray);
            }
        }
    });
```

Model Class

```
 public class sampleArray {

    String id;
    Map<String,String> samplearray;

    public Map<String, String> getSamplearray() {
        return samplearray;
    }

    public void setSamplearray(Map<String, String> samplearray) {
        this.samplearray = samplearray;
    }

    public sampleArray(Map<String,String> samplearray) {
        this.samplearray = samplearray;

    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

}
```

db results are here

[image: db results are here]

Basically what i want is  something like this,

- ---- autogenerated ID
    --- id:XXXXX
    ---member:XXXXX

and not this

---- autogenerated ID

---sampleArray

--- id:XXXXX

---member:XXXXX

How can I remove this string "sample array" because what I know is from model class but I don't know why it appears there.  OR if there any trick on array concept to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

First off all, the link in your question is about Cloud Firestore and not Firebase Realtime database. But, in order to achieve a database structure that looks like this:

```
Firebase-root
    |
    --- member
          |
          --- autogenerated ID
                   |
                   --- id: "XXXXX"
                   |
                   --- name: "XXXXX"
```

Please use the following model class:

```
public class MemberModel {
    private String id, name;

    public MemberModel() {}

    public MemberModel(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

And to add data to the database, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference memberRef = rootRef.child("member");
String id = memberRef.push().getKey();
Member member = new Member("member 1", id);
memberRef.child(id).setValue(member);
```

Comment: what if i want to update multiple item from recyclerview @Alex Mamo

Comment: If you want to update, you need to use instead of the `setValue()` method, `updateChildren` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with hashmaps, just do this in order to achieve what you want. So just change this line:

```
memberDatabaseReference.child(id).setValue(sampleArray);
```

to this:

```
memberDatabaseReference.child(id).updateChildren(member);
```

Remember that:

- `setValue` method is totally replacing the document (specified reference) with new data
- `updateChildren` method is just updating particular fields or add such fields if they did not exist before.